# How can i make a component fixed in the window for specific scrolling intervals

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend

I'm trying to replicate a component like the sidebar on [this](https://www.airbnb.com/experiences/1412905?currentTab=experience_tab&federatedSearchId=530f0051-6a4a-4723-bb33-a898ee274589&searchId=&sectionId=52c2d474-093e-4cdd-ab02-2cf71126f2e2&source=p2&modal=PHOTO_TOUR_SCROLLABLE) airbnb page. What's the best way to have a component which stays fixed until you scroll past a section of the page? I'm using functional React and Material-UI components and I'm pretty new to Front End development and typescript/html/css in general, so apologies if this has been answered elsewhere. I'm unsure what the best way to describe the problem is, so i've had trouble finding solutions online.

Comment: You can inspect the element to know how they did it. In your case you need to set position property to `sticky` and the top position to the height of the navbar + some padding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `position: sticky` and `top:0` to achieve this.

Here `top:0` is set here to stick to the top of the page if you want some space above it feel free to set `top:50px` or something like your wish

This will stick your content if the content reach the top of the viewport

```css
div{display: block;}

.some_top_content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.container::after {
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  content: '';
}

*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.left_content {
  height: 800px;
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  background: blue;
}

.right_content {
  width: 48%;
  float: right;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height:  400px;
  background: green;
}

.some_bottom_content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="some_top_content"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left_content"></div>
  <div class="right_content"></div>
</div>
<div class="some_bottom_content"></div>
```

PS: Run this snippet in full page view

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/wvexQpY)

Comment: brilliant! thank you! this was one of the position types i had yet to learn..

Comment: You can refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position or https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp  for more details